# Rails 3: ensure calling controller method from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

Rails 3.2.6. I have a following controller-view combination (simplified, in reality assignments are to results of some model calls):

`ApplicationController`:

```
def set_menu_vars
  @var1 = 1
  @var2 = 2
end
```

`SomeController < ApplicationController`:

```
def some_action
  set_menu_vars
end
```

corresponding (partial, shared) view (haml):

```
- if @var1 > 0
  %p= @var1
```

So far so good, until I forget in some action to call `set_menu_vars` - now I get an exception `undefined method '>' for nil:NilClass`.  This is quite understandable, and I want to ensure that if that partial view is used, `set_menu_vars` is called automagically.

So I try to modify view as

```
- @controller.set_menu_vars
...
```

(googled) but get analogous exception saying that `@controller` is `nil`.  Well, these answers seem to be for Rails 2, seeing .  I tried to change to

```
- controller.set_menu_vars
...
```

Now `set_menu_vars` is called successfully, but `@var1` is still `nil` in the view.

So the question is: what is the right way to accomplish the task?  Have a method in the controller for each of these variables (looking for instance variable to make the call to model at most once)?  Or some other way?

*UPD*: the partial view in question is not directly relevant to the controller and its action.  This is logically part of layout (dashboard showing links to groups of tasks that may require attention).  So this is very natural for forget to call `set_menu_vars` in several `if` branches among about half of controller actions.  On the other side, `set_menu_vars` does some not so short queries to database, so I want it to be called if and only if it is needed (that is, if the view in question is really rendered).

Answer (score 1):

Its not the 'Rails Way'.

The controller calls the method from the model.

model(article.rb):

```
def do_something
 code
end
```

controller(articles_controller.rb):

```
def index
 @article = Article.do_something
end
```

view(articles/index.html.erb)

```
<%= @article %>
```

Sorry if i misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yes, you misunderstood my question, probably because I am not clear enough in asking it.  See UPD, please.